# 1/4" to 1" gaps in corners of my newly "professionally" installed drywall

Tags: drywall

The drywall in my bathroom was put up yesterday, & has yet to be taped & miffed in. There are considerable uneven( up to an inch ) gaps in 2 of my inside corners. I don't want to let them start mudding, & end up with chipping or sloppy corners in my new bathroom. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tell them that you don't pay by the hour for putting 10 layers of drywall mud in a gap?  I don't think you'd be out of line bringing it to their attention.

Comment: You shouldn't end up with chipping/sloppy corners, but they'll probably have to hit those spots an extra time or two with mud after taping, because as the mud dries it will tend to pull inward a little.

Comment: Do you have pictures?

Comment: Some guys do use corner strips for inside corners and a big gap would end up looking just like everything else.  Why are you concerned?  Have they messed up other things?

Comment: I agree with Dmoore, I know several sheetrock contractors that use corner bead on every external corner and some on inside if it saves another sheet. + the best way to get a better opinion would be to post a photo.

Answer (score 1):

It might look sloppy now, but if they are conscientious when taping and finishing, that will not be a problem in the least. It really would only take one quick setting-type coat before taping to get even a 1 inch gap as ready for tape as any other corner. (Assuming there is blocking behind it to back up the compound - there should be, otherwise what is the drywall attached to?). It's important though that the corner tape reaches the drywall - if it doesn't, there needs to be an additional run of tape over the filled-in gap. But other than that slight setback, the finished corner will be as nice as any other corner.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you as a 52-year-old professional house painter: The tighter the drywall is the fewer problems you will have down the road. Even if your drywall guy pre-muds the gaps you will eventually have a problem with the mud shrinking and falling out. I fix plenty of these problems every year. When I pulled the loose inside corners I always find that the mud behind the tape has failed in the big gaps.

Comment: I would disagree if corners are used.